# How do I add a custom work item type to a group in TFS2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have created a custom work item type in TFS2010 and I think I need to add it to the Requirements Group to make it show up in Testing Center (Work Items can be found, but my new type cannot even if I set the search filter to explicitly look for it). How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I finally found something helpful on MSDN. You have to use [witadmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx)

Open a VS2010 command prompt and get the categories like this:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>witadmin exportcategories /collection:http://win-gs9gmujits8:8080/tfs/defaultcollection /p:"My Project Name" /f:categories.xml
```

Then this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286631.aspx) explains the syntax of the categories xml file. I added my custom work item type in like this:

```
<CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" name="Requirement Category">
  <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="User Story" />
  <WORKITEMTYPE name="My Custom Work Item Type" />
</CATEGORY>
```

Then you reimport them using the witadmin tool again:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents>witadmin importcategories /collection:http://win-gs9gmujits8:8080/tfs/defaultcollection /p:"My Project Name" /f:categories.xml
```

And now Testing Center is able to assign the new work item types as requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than fiddling with XML, you can use the **TFS PowerTools**.

See here:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f

`Tools > Process Editor > Work Item Types`

[image]